# LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable

Tags: compiling, environment-variables, libraries, dynamic-linking

I am trying to test the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. I have a program `test.c` as follows:

```
int main()
{
     func("hello world");
}
```

I have two files func1.c and func2.c:

```
// func1.c
#include <stdio.h>
void func(const char * str)
{
     printf("%s", str);
}
```

And

```
// func2.c
#include <stdio.h>
void func(const char * str)
{
     printf("No print");
}
```

I want to do the following somehow:

- Convert `func1.c` and `func2.c` to .so files - both with same name `func.so` (they will be placed in different folders, say `dir1` and `dir2`
- Compile `test.c` s.t. I only mention that it has a dependency `func.so`, but I don't tell it where it is (I want the environment variable to be used to find this)
- Set the environment variable, in first try to `dir1` and in second try to `dir2` to observe different output in each run of `test` program

Is the above doable ? If so, how to do step 2 ?

I did the following for step 1 (same steps for func2):

```
$ gcc -fPIC -g -c func1.c
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o func.so func1.o
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ld -soname`:

```
$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o dir1/func.so func1.c -Wl,-soname,func.so
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o dir2/func.so func2.c -Wl,-soname,func.so
$ gcc test.c dir1/func.so
$ ldd a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffda80d7000)
    func.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f639079e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6390b68000)
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$ORIGIN/dir1:$ORIGIN/dir2' ./a.out
hello world
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$ORIGIN/dir2:$ORIGIN/dir1' ./a.out
No print
```

`-Wl,-soname,func.so` (this means `-soname func.so` is passed to `ld`) embeds `SONAME` attribute of `func.so` in the output.  You can examine it by `readelf -d`:

```
$ readelf -d dir1/func.so 

Dynamic section at offset 0xe08 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [func.so]
...
```

Linked with this `func.so` with `SONAME`, `a.out` has that in its `NEEDED` attribute:

```
$ readelf -d a.out

Dynamic section at offset 0xe18 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [func.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

Without `-Wl,-soname,func.so`, you'll get the following by `readelf -d`:

```
$ readelf -d dir1/func.so 

Dynamic section at offset 0xe18 contains 24 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...

$ readelf -d a.out

Dynamic section at offset 0xe18 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [dir1/func.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
...
```

Comment: Why after specifying `func.so` in `dir1`, still results in not found in `ldd` after the `gcc` step ?

Comment: Updated my answer.  It's because `NEEDED is set to `func.so` and dynamic linker (`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) cannot find it in library search path.  `ld` sets it to `SONAME` if DSO has it, otherwise the path name passed in arguments.

Comment: I tried a similar test, but instead to create a dummy `libc.so.6` library (the library C file just has a `printf()` definition which is empty). When I try to run my test program (which depends on `libc.so.6` and uses `printf()`), it displays: `symbol __cxa_finalize not defined` .. what does that mean ?

Comment: Executables and DSOs created by `gcc` depend on many symbols in `libc.so.6` implicitly.  Your own `libc.so.6` must provide all of them as original `libc.so.6` does.  `readelf -s (your)program | grep UND` and `readelf -s (your)libc.so.6 | grep UND` show such symbols undefined and to be provided by others.  Regarding just replacing `printf()` in `libc.so.6`, you might want to use `LD_PRELOAD` hook of glibc.  There are many docs and resources on this topic, for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/4937930).